# Matlab: How to find indices of a specific value in vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, find

How can I find the indices of a specific value in a vector? For example in the following vector:

```
B = [2 3 4 5 2 7 9 2]
```

I need the index of all occurrences of 2, which is: `[1 5 8]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`find`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) can be used for this purpose as follows:

```
find(B==2)
```

or an alternative:

```
ind = 1:numel(B);
ind(B==2)
```